# User Consent Screen Shows Up After Access Token Expires

Tags: google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to integrate Google Calendar API in one of my Google App Engine project based off Spring Boot. Using JAVA based google-client-api library for authorization. I provide the client id and secret created in my App Engine project to the `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`. On my first run, I got a user consent screen and after accepting it, `StoredCredential` file was created in target/tokens. After this, all my Google Calendar API calls works fine. After sometime, which I guess is related to expiration of access token, I again get the user consent screen. As per the documentation, if access type is set to `offline`, the authorization flow will take care of managing the refresh tokens. `StoredCredential` file is still there in the target/tokens path but I still see the user consent screen. Pasting snippet of the authorization code.

```
  private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = EventController.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
  }

  public static Calendar get() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client com.huddle.processor.service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    return new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
  }
```

Update:
While remote debugging that when google-oauth-client fetches the stored credential from file using

```
StoredCredential stored = credentialDataStore.get(userId);
```

refresh token is null. Wondering if this is the cause, though not sure why it not getting set.

Would be great if someone can let me know what am I missing. Thanks

Comment: Delete the credentials for the user and have them login again.   If that doesn't work go to the users google account and have them remove authorization for your app an try again.   You should be getting an access token back

Comment: thanks @DaImTo, found the solution and posted it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this. It was related to not being able to get refresh token. Needed to pass approval_prompt=force parameter. so the updated code snippet was

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .setApprovalPrompt("force")
        .build();
```

Reference blog which helped me : https://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/10/upcoming-changes-to-oauth-20-endpoint.html